XSRF Token missing from POST request after deployment to Cloud Run

Using Laravel 11, Inertia & React -> Docker Image -> Cloud Run
After opening the app on / I get redirected to /login as expected.
Inspecting the network requests up to that point, X-XSRF headers and cookies are present on requests and responses.
After entering the login/password and submitting the form, I get redirected to "419 Page Expired". The network request does not contain any X-XSRF headers or cookies at this point.
In contrast: Running the image locally, login works and the request has X-XSRF tokens.

I tried myriad ways to force the XSRF token to be included, like including the hidden input fields on forms, messing with middleware and various config settings. It wasn't until recently that I noticed the earlier requests (before the form submission) actually do include the tokens already. Inertia supposedly handles this automatically.
Now I've been trying to come up with more ways to get to the bottom of this.
Here's the request, for completeness I suppose:
POST /login HTTP/3
Host: inertia-react-162956230927.asia-northeast2.run.app
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:130.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/130.0
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 70
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
X-Inertia: true
X-Inertia-Version: ba6fd3500ad1fa8ab5152eef0ed1845b
Origin: https://inertia-react-162956230927.asia-northeast2.run.app
Connection: keep-alive
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin

As you can see there is no X-XSRF token, even though it should be expected to be there.
On the earlier GET requests to the login page, this was part of the response:
XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI(...)iIn0%3D; expires=Wed, 02 Oct 2024 04:24:58 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; domain=inertia-react-162956230927.asia-northeast2.run.app; samesite=lax
I truncated the token itself. I guess if you want to, you can visit the domain from the GET request yourself and see what's up.
For now I'm hoping that someone could point out either A: something I'm apparently misunderstanding here or B: other ways to analyze and isolate the problem, or C: wrap my head around this to understand what's going on.
PS: The project itself is mostly the same as from this tutorial https://youtu.be/VrQRa-afCAk?si=BX23_FzKshzscERW and is to be remodeled when deployment issues are figured out. Not that I'm expecting anyone to watch the 5h video, but perhaps someone is familiar with the setup...

An update: I have since tried opening the app with Chrome instead of Firefox. It turns out that Chrome indeed displays an XSRF cookie on the request. This would suggest the issue is not with a missing header. It seems some people have had trouble depending on which value they had set in their session_driver env variable, but I tried all kinds of options for that and still had no luck.
That is all I can say so far.

Well, after nearly despairing and trying everything that worked for others and remotely resembled my problem, I stumbled upon a solution by chance.
In resources/js/bootstrap.js I added these two lines:
window.axios.defaults.withCredentials = true; 
window.axios.defaults.withXSRFToken = true;

Even though examining the Network requests in the browser, the XSRF token now seemed to be present, perhaps it was nevertheless not getting transmitted correctly, or something was wrong with it.
Here's where I found the solution that worked for me: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/inertia/laravel-10-inertia-error-419-on-production
The user JussiManisto also offered a possible explanation in there, which I'm going to quote here.

Axios received a CVE in October regarding the withCredentials option. As a result the behavior of the option was changed so that it no longer automatically adds the XSRF header to cross-origin requests. They later added the withXSRFToken option to mimic the old behavior.
Do note that adding withXSRFToken adds the token to all requests. This is what the CVE was about. So use different Axios settings if you're sending requests to 3rd party APIs and don't want to leak your XSRF token.

